# In an activity, if the activity is paused and then invoked with an intent, getIntent() returns the old one

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I have an activity that shows some information based on the intent that initiates the activity. The app icon starts this activity without any extra information and the activity displays correctly. The app widget also starts this activity, but with some extra information and is handled correctly. In this scenario, the app does not work as expected:

The user enters the activity using home screen shortcut.
The user uses the home key to send the app to the background.
The user uses the widget shortcut to enter the app

in this scenario, in onResume() the intent is the old one not the one from widget.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly why [onNewIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) exists: it is called:

> when the activity is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch it.
>
> An activity will always be paused before receiving a new intent, so you can count on `onResume()` being called after this method.
>
> Note that `getIntent()` still returns the original Intent. You can use `setIntent(Intent)` to update it to this new Intent.

Therefore add code such as:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent (Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

And/or move your code from `onResume()` into a method such as `handleIntent()` and call it from both your `onCreate()` and from `onNewIntent()`.